# Pushing AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server logs to cloudwatch

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, real-time, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to check if there is way I can push AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server logs to CloudWatch.

I had a look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html

It has links for:

- MariaDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL

But not Microsoft SQL Server.

Is there a way I can export AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server logs to CloudWatch in real time?